# How frequent are permutations with small interleaving?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, permutations, random-permutations

For $S\subset [n]:=\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$, define $\delta(S)$ to be the number of $m\in S$ such that $m+1\notin S$.

Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $[n]$. For simplicity, assume that $\pi$ is an $n$-cycle. Define the *interleaving* $I(\pi)$ to be the largest $d$ such that there are $i\in [n]$, $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $\delta(S)=d$ for $S = \{i, \pi(i),\dotsc, \pi^{k-1}(i)\}$.

For fixed $n$, how many $n$-cycles $\pi$ are there with given $I(\pi)$? Asymptotically, how common are $n$-cycles with $I(\pi)$ less than a given $r$, say?

Comment: Not that it isn't obvious, but in the definition of $\delta(S)$ a parameter other than $n$ in the second half might be convenient (since it's bound in the first half). Slightly more seriously should we interpret $n+1$ to equal 1? That is, is $\delta(\{1,n\})$ equal to 1 or to 2?

Comment: Ooops, changed.

Comment: On whether $n+1$ equals $1$: whatever makes you happier.

Comment: It looks that usually interleaving is about $n/4$: if we take a random subset $T$ with $\alpha n$ elements, it has about $\alpha(1-\alpha)n$ elements $x$ for which $x+1\notin T$, that is maximal for $\alpha=1/2$. And concentration inequalities show that greater interleaving is very unlikely (even after we multiply by the choice of $i$ and $k$ in your terms), and smaller interleaving is very unlikely even for $i=1,k=[n/2]$.

Comment: Sure, but how unlikely is unlikely? How many $\pi$ are there with $I(\pi)$ bounded? Is it about $O(C^n)$ or thereabouts, or is it more like $n!/2^n$?

Comment: @HAHelfgott ah, this seems to be $O(C^n)$. If $I(\pi)<M$, then the permutation $(1,\pi(1),\pi^2(1),\dots,\pi^{n-1}(1))$ should be $\sigma$-avoiding for $\sigma=(1,3,5,\dots,2M-1,2,4,\ldots,2M-2)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma$-avoiding?

Comment: Ah, I see, the Stanley-Wilf conjecture (now a theorem). Nice. Was this case known before?

Comment: You mean, was this corollary known? No idea.

Comment: Well, this pattern. Though actually weneed something weaker (our permutations would have to avoid large families of patterns). It's relevant, since I want to see what happens as $M$ increases.

Comment: A lower bound of about $n^r r^n$ for the number of $\pi$'s with $I(\pi)\leq r$ seems easy to prove. Perhaps there is also an upper bound of roughly that quality?